# How to select what version of Python Spyder will open on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu, anaconda

I have been struggling with multiple versions of Python on Ubuntu 16.04. I have versions 2.7 and 3.5. I have followed the steps from the [Anaconda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html) site as to how to switch from one environment to another with "source activate snakes". That works well when just looking at the default when calling python from the terminal, but when I attempt to open spyder IDE, no matter what other version is the default, it just opens on python 2.7.

Any ideas how this can be switched in a non permanent way, since I need both versions of Python?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have spyder3? I have spyder and spyder3. Depending on which of those spyders I'm opening the default python would be 2.7 for spyder and 3.5 for spyder3. I open spyders from terminal in ubuntu. That might not be the most reasonable solution, but it works.

Comment: Ah, nice one!! I have Spyder(2), so I am going to install Spyder 3 as well. Are there any specifics for the installation of Spyder 3 for working with Python 3? Can I just install it from the terminal with apt-get install?

Comment: Sure. You just do: "sudo apt-get install spyder3" and forget all your troubles ;)